# How to print updated values of a composable in a vue-component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, composable

I am using `vue3` with `options API`.As shown in the below posted code, in the class `test.js` should be a composable class. i want this class to reflect the change of `state` in another `vue-component`. in other words, the value of `state` changes
as eminent in the code, i want to reflect the updated value of `state` in a `vue-component`. i want the `vue-component` to display the different states set in the `test.js`

to achieve that, i made the `state` of type `ref` as shown in the code.

in the `vue-component` as shonw below, i call and display the contents of `state = useState()` in '  state: {{state }}' and i expect the states to be displayed are `not-satrted`,`started`, `processing` and `successful`. But that does not happend.

how can i print updated values of `state` from `test.js` in a `vue-component` please.

**vue-component**:

```
<template>
    <span> state: {{state }}</span>
</template>

<script>
    import { useStates } from '../xx/xx/xxx/test.js';
    const state = useStates();
```

**test.js**

```
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

// by convention, composable function names start with "use"
export function useStates() {
  let state = ref('not-satrted')

  setTimeout(() => {
    state.value = 'started'
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    state.value = 'processing'
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    state.value = 'successful'
  }, 3000);
  // expose managed state as return value
  return state 
}
```

Comment: you should use `<script setup>` on the fly instead of trying to use the `setup() ` function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i figured it out. i did not add `state` to `data` object.it should be added to `data` object in the `vue-component` as follows:

```
data() {
    return {
        state,
        ....
        ....
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You [should not](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#using-composables-in-options-api) use composables out of `setup()`

Comment: can you provide an example please

Comment: It's a comment and not a real answer. You can use them but this is decided on the implementation. Reactivity api supports that usage but some things (notable provide/inject) obviously don't

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Amrmsmb The answer looks ok to me